# MS Word desde VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

Tengo la siguiente Forma con código:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 
Public Class Form1
    **Dim oWord as New Word.Application()** 
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Add()
        dim oParas = oDoc.Paragraphs 
        dim oPara = oParas.Add() 
        dim oParaRng = oPara.Range 
        oParaRng.Text = "Heading 1" 
        dim oFont = oParaRng.Font 
        oFont.Bold = 1 
        oParaRng.InsertParagraphAfter() 

        dim oBookmarkRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range 
 
 
        Dim oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oBookmarkRng, 5, 2) 
        oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6 
 
 
        For r As Integer = 1 To 5 
            For c As Integer = 1 To 2 
                oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "r" & r & "c" & c 
            Next 
        Next 
 
        ' Change width of columns 1 & 2 
        oTable.Columns(1).Width = oWord.InchesToPoints(2) 
        oTable.Columns(2).Width = oWord.InchesToPoints(3) 
        oDoc.Close() 
        oWord.Quit(False) 

    End Sub
End Class
```

Copiado de internet, ya que he intentado por distintas formas de hacer la conexión y en todas las probadas me da el error (En la linea marcada con ** o en negritas) siguiente:

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' en mscorlib.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>
> Información adicional: No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente error: 80080005
>
> Error en la ejecución de servidor (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

En otros casos (Probando) me dice que no puede crear el control activex.

**¿Qué puede estar mal, o que no he hecho para que esto funcione?**

Mi ambiente es: Windows 10 64 Bits. Visual Studio 2015 y Office 2013

Comment: Hola. Añade todo tu código en su respectivo bloque de código. Selecciona todo el código y pulsa Ctrl+K. De otra manera no se llega a leer nada.

Comment: Tienes declarada tu variable entre ** : ** Dim oWord as New Word.Application() **

Comment: Lamentablemente no leiste totalmente mi pregunta, Inmediatamente después del código dice: "el error (En la linea marcada con ** o en negritas) "

Answer (score 2):

Estimado lo único cambio es la siguiente linea, prueba con ello, si aún te sale error verifica que tu Word esté licenciado, osea que no te muestre la ventana con titulo color rojo de licencia.

```
'Dim oWord As New Word.Application()
```

por

```
Dim oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Ya que en lo personal era el error que me mostraba el vb.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a inicializar tu variable `oWord` de la siguiente manera:

```
Dim oWord As Object
oWord = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, el error continua...